# Can DateTime.UtcNow and Environment.TickCount get out of sync over a long running execution on a Windows system?

Tags: c#, .net

By out of sync I mean, if when starting up my program I get an initial value for DateTime and tickcount, if after some period of time (let's say 1 weeks for example) I check the value for these 2 and calculate the elapsed time for each, will they show significant variation (assume significant here means more than half a second)? Let's also assume nothing messed with the system clock during that period so DateTime wasn't affected by that.

Comment: No, they use the same clock source.  Stopwatch and DateTime however will get out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very badly worded, so let me start by rephrasing it in a more rigorous way:

> If at a moment A in time you start a `Stopwatch` (the equivalent of your tick count thing) and store `DateTime.Now`, and then at a later point in time B you stop the stopwatch and take a second `DateTime.Now` snapshot, with there be any significat difference between the two deltas?

The answer to that is no, as long as the OS was powered on the entire time. Hibernation and sleep will (obviously) not increase the OS tick count, but the internal clock will keep ticking.